# The changes I made in the css file are not applied

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a project in Asp.Net Core Mvc in Visual Studio. My project have a css folder. My css codes are effective but when i want to change something in this css file, the changes are not apply. Then I copy all codes to another file, my problem fixed but a few laters same mistake occurs, again I cant change css codes. How can I fix this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the reasons of this issue could be browser caching the old css in file, as a solution is to append a parameter to your css source like a timestamp

Then your CSS tag becomes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssfile.css?t=<%= DateTime.Now.Ticks %>" media="screen" />
```

Comment: With existing solution for cache-busting: `asp-append-version="true"`, I would not recommend your approach because it causes unnecessary high load on server and downgraded response times.